# why we still have the sun_family in the struct sockaddr_un?

Tags: c, sockets, unix

I'm a newbie in UNIX programming. Normally, when we use local socket to communicate, the domain is always AF_UNIX or AF_LOCAL. So in this case, struct sockaddr_un serves always for the local communication. Why there is still "short sun_family"? For a historical reason?

```
struct sockaddr_un{
short sun_family;                /*AF_UNIX*/ 
char  sun_PATH[108];        /*path name */ 
};
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You pass a `sockaddr *` to several socket functions (e.g. `connect`, `bind`, `sendto`) - these will look at the family variable before casting to e.g. `sockaddr_un *` or `sockaddr_in *`